# SVG2TikZ or Inkscape2TikZ: convert from SVG graphics to TikZ/PGF code

Tags: inkscape, tools, latex

`Inkscape` is a graphics program that has several extensions. One of this tool for exporting SVG pciture is `TikZ/PGF`. From this page https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz `SVG2TikZ`, there are a set of tools for converting `SVG graphics` to `TikZ/PGF code`.

Could someone please explain to me how to correctly install `svg2tikz` in InkScape and how to export the code to `TikZ`?

I have seen this link https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz/blob/master/docs/install.rst#automatic-installation-via-a-package-manager but not having installed InkScape on my computer I can't imagine how to install it correctly.

Comment: Important data: What operating system are you using? First guess, based on "via-a-package-manager" is that you are using some form of Linux?

Comment: @fred_dot_u OS Windows 10. I did not understand very well how to install it even if there is a question here about TeXstack: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98594/how-to-convert-an-svg-image-with-latex-in-inkscape-to-png

Comment: Why do you expect the extension to work, if you don't even have Inkscape installed?

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited your post because requesting a video will likely attract downvotes and decreases searchability for our other members. Answerers will try to help you in ways they see fit. As it stands, I'm not sure your question is [on-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Emilie You did very well to edit my matter and I thank you. I don't come here often. I like to ask and know, but not be insulted.

Comment: @downvoter: Is there a true reason for a downvote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the instructions, all you need to do is to copy the .inx and .py files from here: 
https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz/tree/master/svg2tikz/extensions

into your user extensions directory (which is listed in Edit > Preferences > System : User extensions).

Then restart (or start) Inkscape.

The extension should be available in the export dialog (as a selectable file type) and in the Extensions menu, under Export.

Comment: Since he hasn't installed Inkscape (hard to understand, because hard to believe), he will not have an user extension directory.